# How to Code Bulk Image Placement in InDesign Using .jsx or .idjs?

Tags: javascript, jsx, adobe-indesign

InDesign Coding **N00B**, here.

Seeking guidance as to practicality and approach to writing .idjs or .jsx code to place ~300 .png image files in an InDesign-based "coffee table book."

- (NB: This is a non-paying job in support of a community
  not-for-profit fundraiser. No funding. Volunteer effort.)

**BACKGROUND**

Using exiftool, each affected .png has been updated with an "xmp-dc:Description" tag that contains the image's caption.

In a single image test via InDesign's PLACE command, InDesign's Caption Setup | Generate Live Caption recognizes and displays the ("Description") Caption just fine.

All images are listed in a .csv that contains:

1. The full macOS path of the image, and
2. The page number where the image is to be placed.

*(At the moment, the author just wants each image placed on their designated page...with intentions of manually repositioning & resizing them later.)*

Example CSV entries:

- "/Users/{name}/ ... /coffeetablebook/images/IMAGE1067.png","42"
- "/Users/{name}/ ... /coffeetablebook/images/IMAGE1022.png","84"
- "/Users/{name}/ ... /coffeetablebook/images/IMAGE1117.png","7"

**REQUEST for YOUR EXPERTISE**

Is there a practical way(s) to write a .jsx or .idjs script that can:

- Open the affected .indd file,
- Open the affected .csv file,
- Loop through the .csv file in order to:

  - Access each image file via its macOS Path,
  - PLACE the accessed image on the specified page,
  - Embed the image file link in the .indd,
  - Apply a defined Caption Setup to the properly placed image,
  - Activate Generate Live Caption for the properly placed image, then

When done looping through the .csv: close the .indd and exit InDesign?

**IDEAL for AUTOMATION? Or...?**

If the above process is ideal for automation (.idjs or .jsx), then hints for this **N00B** as to how to approach coding a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Or, should I abandon the idea of automating this task--and ~300 times--manually place the images on their page, embed the link, apply Caption Setup, activate Generate Live Caption, et cetera?

- *Oh, did I mention? ~300 times! (Ugh!)*

Suggestions and insights are invited and welcomed!

With great gratitude from someone that is dreading 300 mind-numbing & repetitive and repetitive & mind-numbing PLACEments, et cetera.

Many thanks,

*Plane Wryter*

Comment: Looks like a perfect and quite easy task for a script. The only thing I'm not sure is the 'description' in a caption. If it's possible to tweak via script. Could you provide a couple pages of the final layout and images with correct captions and descriptions. It makes sense to see what the result should look like.

Answer (score 2):

Basically this simple script can do it:

```
app.doScript(main, ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT, undefined, UndoModes.FAST_ENTIRE_SCRIPT, 'Place images');

function main() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var images = get_list_of_images_from_csv();
    var frames = [];

    // place images on the pages
    for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
        var image = images[i];
        var page = doc.pages.itemByName(image.page);

        // UPDATED LINES
        var pic = page.place(image.path)[0];
        resize(pic, 432);
        frames.push(pic.parent);
    }

    // align frames by center of pages, why not?
    for (var i=0; i<frames.length; i++) {
        var frame = frames[i];
        doc.align(frame, AlignOptions.HORIZONTAL_CENTERS, AlignDistributeBounds.PAGE_BOUNDS);
        doc.align(frame, AlignOptions.VERTICAL_CENTERS, AlignDistributeBounds.PAGE_BOUNDS);
    }

    // add captions to the placed images
    // it uses the caption settings of the current document
    // I don't know if you can change the settings via a srcipt
    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
        app.selection = frames[i];
        try {
            app.menuActions.item('$ID/Generate Live Caption').invoke();
        } catch(e) {}
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------

function get_list_of_images_from_csv() {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var csv_file = doc.filePath.getFiles('*.csv')[0] || doc.fullName;
    csv_file = csv_file.openDlg("Select CSV file");
    if (!csv_file) exit();

    csv_file.encoding = 'UTF-8';
    csv_file.open('r');
    var contents = csv_file.read().split('\n');
    csv_file.close();

    var images = []; // the array of objects [{path, page}, {path, page}, ...]
    while (contents.length) {
        var row = contents.shift().split(','); // a path shouldn't contain comma!
        if (row.length == 0 || row[0] == '' || row[1] == '') continue;
        var path = row[0].replace(/"/g,''); // remove quote marks
        var page = row[1].replace(/"/g,''); // remove quote marks
        images.push({path: path, page: page});
    }

    return images;
}

// function to resize an image by height (px)
function resize(pic, target_height) {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    // save doc units
    var vert_units = doc.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits;
    var horiz_units = doc.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits;

    // change doc units to px
    doc.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.PIXELS
    doc.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.PIXELS

    // change size of the picture
    var pic_height = pic.geometricBounds[2] - pic.geometricBounds[1];
    pic.horizontalScale = 100 * target_height / pic_height;
    pic.verticalScale = 100 * target_height / pic_height;
    pic.parent.geometricBounds = pic.geometricBounds; // resize the frame

    // restore original doc units
    doc.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = vert_units;
    doc.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = horiz_units;
}
```

It takes CSV file like this (note: if a path contains a comma `,` there will be an error):

```
"/Users/me/Documents/test/001.tif","1"
"/Users/me/Documents/test/011.tif","3"
"/Users/me/Documents/test/012.tif","4"
```

And puts the images on the pages of current open document:

[image]

It adds the captions with the caption settings of the current document. It doesn't change the settings. I don't know if it's possible to change the settings via a script.

Comment: Yuri! AWESOME! Worked "out of the box," and solved the problem. Your helpful script can be a boon to many. Please consider adding it to the Adobe Exchange! (https://exchange.adobe.com). With gratitude, Plane Wryter

Comment: new problem. Although the source images were sized...when they are placed on a page, InDesign is resizing them. (I suspect this has to do with properties of the enclosing frame, but do not know.) Is there a way to augment your code to specify height = 432px for all frames/images...with the proportional width being retained?  (Example 1: h:432px, w:816px, proportion 1.889; Example 2: h:432px, w:313px, proportion: 0.722; Example 3: h:432px, w:220px, proportion: 0.509; Example 4: h:432px, width: 967px, proportion: 2.238. Your thoughts?

Comment: Easy-peasy. ) See the updated code. I just added a couple lines in the main section and added the new function to resize an image as it's pasted on a page. Probably you can add the code on Exchange by your self if you want. It's not copyrighted as soon as it posted on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Btw, as you can see, the most part of the resize function is switching between the measurement units (original units > pixels > original units). If your document already uses pixels as main units you can comment out these lines, this way it will work a bit faster.